# No guarda la cadena dentro del vector

Tags: c

Hola en este codigo me da un error cuando le pido al usuario que ingrese una cadena y que modifique la que yo ya ingrese que es "perro", el problema esta en estas lineas

```
printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
    scanf("%s",(vector+1));
```

si no las pongo funciona bien, pero yo quiero que el usuario pueda modificar ese "perro" que yo di.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,a;
    char **vector;

    vector = (char**)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));

    *(vector) = "hola";
    *(vector + 1) = "perro";
    printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
    scanf("%s",(vector+1));

    puts("\nImprimiendo caracter a caracter:");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0; j<strlen(*(vector+i)) ; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",*(*(vector+i)+j));
        }
        puts("");
    }

    puts("\nImprimiendo completo:");
    printf("%s\n",*vector);
    printf("%s",*(vector+1));

    free(vector);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu no puedes modificar un char*, yo lo haría así, es mas simple y limpio.
No se si es la mejor solución ya que estoy aprendiendo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 100

int main()
{
    int i,j,a;

    char vector[MAXLINE] = "hola "; 
    char temp[MAXLINE] = "perro"; // string temporal para concatenar hola con la modificacion

    printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
    fgets(temp, MAXLINE, stdin); // obtener el input del usuario

    strcat(vector, temp); // concatenar tu vector con lo que el usuario ingreso
    printf("%s", vector); // imprimirlo por pantalla

    return 0;
}
```